# What is the standardized naming of this type of coffee?

Tags: ground-coffee, coffee-machines

What is the "standard" name for this type of coffee in the various countries (I mean made from these type of machines with the paper filter)?

[image]

I have noticed when travelling that in some coffee spots in various countries in Europe, this type of coffee is not available. Unless it has a different naming than I am aware.
Is this called American coffee? Because I know that Americano is a type of espresso so it is not the same

Comment: You are asking about names in *Europe*, right?

Comment: @Stephie:Yes because in US it is just regular coffee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The drip-type coffee is available in many countries in Europe. A list of names:

- *Filterkaffee* in Germany / Austria / Switzerland
- *filterkaffe* in Denmark and Sweden
- *filterkoffie* in the Netherlands
- *kawa filtrowana* in Poland
- *café filtre* in France / Switzerland / Belgium
- *café filtro* in Spain
- *caffè preperato con il filtro* in Italy / Switzerland

Can you see a pattern here: Always a combination of *coffee* and *filter/filtered*. The terms are so closely related that if you order "*filtered coffee*" an attentive waiter should be able to help you even if you don't know the precise term at your destination.

Note that if you order "coffee" *without specifying the preparation*, you will be served the local "default". This will actually be filtered coffee in many countries of Northern and Central Europe, in Italy, as counter-example, you will get what you'd call "espresso", likewise in Spain or Portugal: small, strong.

Asking for *caffè americano* will *perhaps* get you an espresso diluted with hot water in some places in Italy (sources vary whether it's a remenant from WW II or started with international tourism), sometimes *caffè all'americana* ("coffee American-style") will get you drip coffee. Likewise in touristy areas of Spain, *café americano* might get you a diluted coffee.

Further north you won't be understood. They will probably direct you to the nearest Starbucks.

---

<sup>Source:

Living and travelling in Europe for decades plus some research for the precise terms.</sup>

Comment: What you say matches my experience. What I can not understand is, that if you go to *any* of these countries that you mention, you will find in the stores for home electronics/appliances a variety of the coffee machines I have displayed in my OP. In a wide variety of brands and are usually the first you see in any of the shelves. But when you try to order such a coffee you get the communication problems that you have pointed out

Comment: @Jim That is easy to explain, but too long for a comment. Shall we meet in chat?

Comment: "filter coffee" in the UK too, although many cafes would not have such a machine, which might explain why ordering it isn't possible :) i.e. it's more of a domestic home machine.

Comment: The subsequent chat discussion can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20611/conversation/follow-up).

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer the question, but since it's already been answered...

My boss recently got back from a two-week trip to Italy, where he was unable to order a drink by the name of "Americano." And if they don't know what you're talking about, which was his case, they hand you an espresso.

So it seems that an Americano, regardless of how the name originated, is now an American drink. Not to say that you couldn't order this anywhere in Italy, but just that it was not the norm in the cafes my boss went to.

Comment: Coffee Americano actually is a name for an espresso variety. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caff%C3%A8_Americano I have encountered this before

Comment: That was my impression too, but apparently is not the case in every Italian Cafe. At least this is what my boss said after returning from Italy.